# Performance: OR conditions in MySQL slow down inner joins significantly?

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, entity-attribute-value

I'm having quite a hard time with the performance of a complex query with joins.

In a nutshell, I have a table **Profile** together with a details table **ProfileEntries**. Profileentries are composed as path/value pairs (*indeed slighlty more complex, because I can have string entries, and numerical entries, but I assume that this is not the source of performance problems*). I want to find all that profiles that certain entries matches.

```sql
select distinct profile0_.id as id1_7_ 
from SCONProfile profile0_ 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent1_ on profile0_.id=profileent1_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent2_ on profile0_.id=profileent2_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent3_ on profile0_.id=profileent3_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent4_ on profile0_.id=profileent4_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent5_ on profile0_.id=profileent5_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent6_ on profile0_.id=profileent6_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent7_ on profile0_.id=profileent7_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent8_ on profile0_.id=profileent8_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent9_ on profile0_.id=profileent9_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent10_ on profile0_.id=profileent10_.profile_id 
inner join SCONProfileEntry profileent11_ on profile0_.id=profileent11_.profile_id 

where (profileent11_.path='AAAAAA/DDDD/Deutsch' and profileent11_.numericalValue=1 or profileent11_.path='AAAAAA/DDDD/Englisch' and profileent11_.numericalValue=1) 
and (profileent10_.path='AAAAAA/WWWWW/EEE' and profileent10_.numericalValue=1 or profileent10_.path='AAAAAA/WWWWW/UUU' and profileent10_.numericalValue=1) 
and profileent9_.path='AAAAAA/RRRR/WWWWW' and (profileent9_.value='Nicht notwendig' or profileent9_.value='SSSS vor Ort beteiligt' or profileent9_.value='zust. LLLL beteiligt') 
and (profileent8_.path='AAAAAA/RRRR/DDDDRRRR' and profileent8_.numericalValue=1 or profileent8_.path='AAAAAA/RRRR/RRRR-RRRR' and profileent8_.numericalValue=1 or profileent8_.path='AAAAAA/RRRR/R2RRR-RRRR' and profileent8_.numericalValue=1 or profileent8_.path='AAAAAA/RRRR/IIIII' and profileent8_.numericalValue=1)
and (profileent7_.path='UUUUUUUU/KKKKKK/DDDDD' and profileent7_.numericalValue=1 or profileent7_.path='UUUUUUUU/KKKKKK/UUUUU' and profileent7_.numericalValue=1 or profileent7_.path='UUUUUUUU/KKKKKK/UUUUSSSS' and profileent7_.numericalValue=1) 
and profileent6_.path='UUUUUUUU/VVVVV/VVVV' and profileent6_.numericalValue>=0 and profileent6_.numericalToValue<=20000000 
and profileent5_.path='UUUUUUUU/IIIII/RRRRR' and profileent5_.value='abcd' 
and profileent4_.path='UUUUUUUU/MMMMMM/DDDDRRRR' and profileent4_.numericalValue>=0 and profileent4_.numericalValue<=24 
and profileent3_.path='UUUUUUUU/MMMMMM/RRRRRRRR' and profileent3_.numericalValue>=0 and profileent3_.numericalValue<=18 
and profileent2_.path='UUUUUUUU/LLLL/MMMMMMMM' and profileent2_.numericalValue>=0 and profileent2_.numericalValue<=100 
and (profileent1_.path='UUUUUUUU/BBBBB/A1' and profileent1_.numericalValue=1 or profileent1_.path='UUUUUUUU/BBBBB/A2' and profileent1_.numericalValue=1 or profileent1_.path='UUUUUUUU/BBBB/A3' and profileent1_.numericalValue=1)
```

(Sorry for reasons of confidentiality I had to anonymize the string values). This query is generated by Hibernate (even with some more joins, but i simplified the query for easier analysis). If I run it against SQLServer or HSQL it is fast as lightning, if I run it against MySQL it is maddening slow.
I have defined indices on all relevant columns, especially on the 'path'-column, which is the most discriminative index. MySQL should be able to use these indices to optimize access.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

returns

```sql
 # id, select_type, table,           type,     possible_keys,                                                      key,                           key_len, ref,                                    rows,  Extra
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent5_' , 'ref',    'path,value,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i',                           'value',                       '103',   'const',                                '1',   'Using where; Using temporary'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent6_' , 'range',  'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue,numericalToValue', 'numericalToValue',            '9',     NULL,                                   '16',  'Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent10_', 'range',  'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'path',                        '103',   NULL,                                   '40',  'Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent11_', 'range',  'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'path',                        '103',   NULL,                                   '40',  'Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent4_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'path',                        '103',   'const',                                '20',  'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent9_' , 'ref',    'path,value,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i',                           'path',                        '103',   'const',                                '20',  'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent2_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'path',                        '103',   'const',                                '20',  'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent3_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'path',                        '103',   'const',                                '20',  'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent1_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i', '9',     'SUPlattform.profileent9_.profile_id',  '251', 'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent7_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i', '9',     'SUPlattform.profileent1_.profile_id',  '251', 'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profileent8_' , 'ref',    'path,FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i,numericalValue',                  'FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i', '9',     'SUPlattform.profile0_.id',             '251', 'Using where; Distinct'
'1',   'SIMPLE',    'profile0_'    , 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY',                                                          'PRIMARY',                     '8',     'SUPlattform.profileent5_.profile_id',  '1',   ''
```

If I understand it correctly, MySQL is not using the **path** index for profileent1_, profileent7_, and profileent8_ but rather the foreign key index **FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i**. Those are the joins, which use OR-clauses in their where-conditions.

- If I replace the OR-Clause by an equivalent IN-Clause doesn't help, same result.
- If I just kick out the second and third parts of the OR-Clause (and
  getting lessresults) the query is fast again.

I have several questions:

1. Is my analysis correct, that OR-Clauses may spoil join performance?
2. Is there any option to give MySQL an hint to use a better index for query optimization? Or: can I restate this query conditions for better optimization?
3. The hardest one: Is there a "simple" way to tell Hibernate to provide those optimizations?

For sake of completeness: Here are the relevant DDL-statments

```sql
CREATE TABLE `SCONProfileEntry` (
  `EntryType` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toValue` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numericalToValue` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numericalValue` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `toValue` (`toValue`),
  KEY `FKeqdw6j0h25txycjtdhotbv6yl` (`deal_id`),
  KEY `FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i` (`profile_id`),
  KEY `numericalValue` (`numericalValue`),
  KEY `numericalToValue` (`numericalToValue`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKeqdw6j0h25txycjtdhotbv6yl` FOREIGN KEY (`deal_id`) REFERENCES `SCONDeal` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKpe40modwh6dhstsmypo9aub9i` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `SCONProfile` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49963 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `SCONProfile` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `institut_BLZ` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKgjcl2p9ws1h72mibx813g5o67` (`institut_BLZ`),
  KEY `FKrlnujjqbbivdouaa1unp1yvxj` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKgjcl2p9ws1h72mibx813g5o67` FOREIGN KEY (`institut_BLZ`) REFERENCES `InstitutsData` (`BLZ`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKrlnujjqbbivdouaa1unp1yvxj` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `UserData` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2299 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you for your kind support

Wallenstein

Comment: MySQL only uses one index on a table in a query, hence it is having to choose whether to use the index on profile_id which will help the join, or the index on path which can narrow down the results after the join. It is possible to force an index ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html ), but it might be best to have a covering index on both profile_id , path and numericalValue.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine just identified the problem:

It is only indirectly related to the **where**-clauses, but rather related to multiple joins. As mentioned in a [blog from Peter Zaitsev (a former developer of MySQL)](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/04/20/joining-many-tables-in-mysql-optimizer_search_depth/): The complexity of the query optimization grows with n! where n is the number of joins.

Thus the solution is, to advise the query-optimizer not to exaggerate optimization by setting the **optimizer_search_depth** to some limited value.

Wallenstein

Comment: To qualify what Zaitsev is saying...  The complexity growth happens when all the tables have similar statistics.  In your case they all have exactly the same statistics since they are all the same.  There in lies one of the ugly problems with key-value (EAV) schema models.

Comment: Yes setting `optimizer_search_depth=1` will decrease the thinking time for the Optimizer.  But still the execution time for the query will be poor.

Answer (score 0):

```
optimizer_search_depth=1
```

to speed up the Optimizer.

```
INDEX(profile_id, path, value),
INDEX(profile_id, path, numericalValue, numericalToValue),
INDEX(profile_id, path, toValue),
```

to speed up the query (some)

Abandon EAV schema design if you want further improvements.

> Is my analysis correct, that OR-Clauses may spoil join performance? -- very much
>
> Is there any option to give MySQL an hint to use a better index for query optimization? Or: can I restate this query conditions for better optimization? -- no
>
> The hardest one: Is there a "simple" way to tell Hibernate to provide those optimizations? -- I have choice words for 3rd party software that gets in the way.  I will spare you the profanity.

I have added a tag for EAV; read through other questions in that area.